# What is the curve drawn by the intersection of two circles that increase their radii at different rates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two circles at different locations with different factor increases in their radii according to time, $t$:

$(x-7.22)^2+y^2= 4t$

$x^2+y^2=2.56 t$

If you take their points of intersection as t increases, what is the curve drawn out? (Here is the desmos page with the equations and their intersection equation, highlight the intersection equation and click play on the variable t for an animation of what i'm talking about)

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k2twjsayaf

---

I also have a question for a case in which the radii increase according to the following:

$
(x-7.22)^2 + y^2 = (-55.125\ln\left(t+5.25\right)+10.5t+\left(55.125\ln\left(5.25\right)\right)^2
$
$
x^2 + y^2 = -56.40625\ln\left(t+5.9375\right)+9.5t+56.40625\ln\left(5.9375\right)
$

The desmos link is again provided:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hdbu5m6pa4

P.S: The second one seems not to follow an ellipse!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A second question has been added to the original

Comment: The second system appears inescapably ["transcendental"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) in the parameter $t$. In that case, eliminating $t$ analytically is problematic at best, and probably requires numerical methods; but it is decidedly not an ellipse. Be that as it may ... Adding a second task to a question after the first task has been addressed in an answer is inappropriate, as it makes the answerer appear to have ignored part of the question. You should post the second question as a *separate* question. (They're free!) You can link to and from this one for context.

Comment: The new thread is located here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530834/how-to-solve-for-the-curve-drawn-by-the-intersection-of-two-circles-that-increas

Answer (score 1):

No need for computations. If you eliminate $t$, you get a quadratic equation in $t$. Then from the animation, the curve is obviously bounded.

*It is an ellipse.*

You find the major axis where the two circles are tangent exteriorly or interiorly ($y=0$). The minor axis can be found where $x$ is the center of the major axis.

Comment: What about in the case: (x-7.2)^2+y^2 = (-55.125ln(t+5.25)+10.5t+55.125ln(5.25))^2 &(x^2+y^2) = -56.40625ln(t+5.9375)+9.5t+56.40625ln(5.9375)

Comment: Don't ask this here. Enter a new question.

Comment: New thread can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530834/how-to-solve-for-the-curve-drawn-by-the-intersection-of-two-circles-that-increas