# How to solve for the curve drawn by the intersection of two circles that increase their radii according to different composite functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have asked a similar question before but it was suggested that I create a new thread for this second part. Here is the link to the old question but I will also restate the problem in this thread:

[What is the curve drawn by the intersection of two circles that increase their radii at different rates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526738/what-is-the-curve-drawn-by-the-intersection-of-two-circles-that-increase-their-r)

I have two circles at different locations that increase their radii at different rates (as t increases):

$
(x-7.22)^2 + y^2 = (-55.125\ln\left(t+5.25\right)+10.5t+\left(55.125\ln\left(5.25\right)\right)^2
$
$
x^2 + y^2 = (-56.40625\ln\left(t+5.9375\right)+9.5t+56.40625\ln\left(5.9375\right))^2
$

What is the curve drawn by their intersection?

Here is the desmos link for an animation of what I'm talking about:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ml3zls6j9h

It was suggested on the last thread that eliminating t analytically might be problematic and that a numerical method might be needed. If so, what is the best method for doing that? I can use python to attain the points but how does one get a reasonable approximate equation for the shape?

Also, here are the equations from which the composite functions (which are on the right of the two above equations) are integrated:

$
y_{1}=(-55.125)/(t+5.25) + 10.5
$

$
y_{2}=(-56.40625)/(t+5.9375) + 9.5
$

P.S: Perhaps a Taylor series could be used to approximate the radii increase and lead to an analytic solution. Unfortunately, I don't know how to approximate these particular functions with a Taylor series so I haven't investigated that avenue.

Comment: Your parenthesis are not balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the two equations and you can express $x$ as a function of $t$. Then $y$ as a function of $t$.

This gives you parametric equations of the curve, and there is little more that you can do.

Comment: So there's no way to find a function which expresses y in terms of x?

Comment: There is some hope that you can express $t$ in terms of $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by means of the function $W$ of Lambert, and from this $x=\rho\cos\theta$, giving you $\theta=f(\rho)$. The final equation will be somewhat monstrous. Have a look there: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_W_de_Lambert#Équations_a_ex_+_bx_+_c_=_0_et_a_ln(x)_+_bx_+_c_=_0 (sorry, not available in English).

Comment: I might just approximate $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ with a polynomial and work from there. I imagine this would be easy to find an analytic solution for?

Comment: @JackMiller: why do yo want an analytic solution ?

Comment: Sorry for not responding -- in the end I used a numerical solution in the end and it worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the usual ways to provide an equation of a curve (using cartesian, parametric, polar equations) are you aware of a special mode of representation of a curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-center_bipolar_coordinate) using (two-center) **bipolar coordinates** here $r_1(t), r_2(t)$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the distance to two fixed points (here the two radii ? This representation can be converted either into parametric representation $(x(t),y(t))$ or into polar representation $\rho=\varphi(\theta)$ as explained in the Wikipedia article.